# What is the difference between git svn init + fetch and git svn clone?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

While trying to use locally Git at my workplace where we use SVN I was searching a lot for how to set everything up. From what I found it seems there are two approaches to the problem, either:

```
git svn clone URL
```

or

```
git svn init URL
git svn fetch
```

Do they differ? If yes then how? If not then why two ways for the same? Or is this just an edge case where they do the same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are the same. Git has many high-level commands which call other more low-level commands. The high-level commands are oriented towards the user to make everyday tasks easy and the low-level commands do a single thing in terms of git's data structures. In git terminology they are called porcelain and plumbing commands.

Cloning is what a user wants to do and this includes initing a repository and fetching commits from an SVN repository which are totally different repository tasks.